# Fridge has a weird smell coming from where the compressor is

Tags: safety, refrigerator, smell

I have a fridge that has some kind of weird smell coming from where the compressor is. Ive checked the wires and any connections to see if theres any burnt wires, theres nothing. Its not really a burning smell. Its something really weird. Is this dangerous to inhale? What can I do about it?

Comment: most fridges have an evaporation tray, where the water drains during the automatic defrost cycle. .... you are probably smelling whatever food was placed inside the fridge, which then permeated the ice .... do your ice cubes have a similar smell?

Comment: @jsotola It might be that because the tray was half full of dirty water.

Comment: @jsotola your comment is a good answer, if one could smell the Freon the question would be why is my fridge not cooling,  could also be a dirty fan causing some smell but the tray would be my first look with the information provided.

Answer (score 2):

Is it a rotten food kind of smell, or an "oily" or metallic kind of smell? If not a rotten food type of smell, it may be a refrigerant leak, in which case your compressor is probably toast by now.

Comment: It's kind of like a gassy smell